# Spartacus Category Routing using Resolver

Tags: angular, routes, spartacus-storefront

Before "ProductListPage" by category is displayed I want to fetch some additional data from backend.
Angular has this route resolver that can be used to do sth before page is loaded.
Is it possible to create route resolver for category route?
If it is not possible any other suggestion (maybe to disable category route and create its own - any example would be welcome)?

I tired to disable category route and create its own, but don't know how to display default listing product page.